# EF Core Database transation null when using AddDbContext dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a context to my servicecollection with:

```
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("My connection string"));
```

a little further I execute a query by getting an instance of the context:

```
var context = serviceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
```

Which throws the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

Strangely the context nor the `DbSet` users is null. When I debug the provided context, I see that both properties `ChangeTracker` and `Model` on de context instance have thrown the following error:

> 'context.ChangeTracker' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

When I replace `AddDbContext` with a `AddSingleton` with an instance made like this:

```
var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseSqlServer("My connetion string");
var context = new MyContext(optionBuilder.Options);

serviceCollection.AddSingleton(context);
```

everything works fine.

I'm using the Microsoft dependency in a .NET Framework 4.6.1 dll project, referenced by a .NET Core 2.1 Console application which simply executes the code in the dll.

Comment: try adding .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer() before .AddDbContext

Comment: How are you creating the scopes? And are you sure no other thread is accessing the DbContext instance?

Comment: My goal was to use the AddDbContextPool because I have a lot of DB requests. Seems like AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer did the trick. Weird I haven't found any documentation on this, guess I should've started from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kriss suggests, adding

> .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()

to the service collection before the `.AddDbContext()` did the trick.

Thanks Kriss!